# ARRANQUE LENTO UBUNTU

Tags: linux, ubuntu

Tengo un problema y es que desde que instale Kali Linux junto a Ubuntu, al iniciar Ubuntu me ponia `"Please enter passphrase for disk (cryptswap1) on none"`

Busque en internet sobre esto y encontra una posible solucion que consistia en pillar la ID asociada simbolicamente a la particion de intercambio (swap) con la orden ll `/dev/disk/by-id` y sustituirla en el fichero (crypttab) quitando la parte de `uuid=.....`

Pues bien eso hice (si pille bien la ID y no la lie que ahora no estoy seguro ) .Reinicie el portatil y ya no me preguntaba eso pero arrancar ahora le tira unos 2 minutos y medio

Alguna solucion para esto?

Comment: Hola, bienvenido a [Stack Overflow en español](https://es.stackoverflow.com). Por favor, lee el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para aprender el funcionamiento básico del sitio. 
Te invito a mirar [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para más info. Un saludo.

Comment: si le erraste de uuid ese es el problema prueba con `cryptsetup luksUUID <device>` cambiando device por el device fisico q esta encriptado si no esta encriptado te avisa